# How to convert normalized data into binary and save to another table using SQL programming?

Tags: asp.net, sql, performance, sql-server-2008

Just wondering whether it is possible to convert highly normalized data into binary and store it in some other table using sql programming without going into asp.net application?

If yes, how?

This might help us to solve a performance issue. Actually we already did this using asp application, and stored binary data into another table. But this is not being executed for larger data set, and there is a time out error occurring on trying to execute same. This is for an e-commerce application built upon asp.net mvc 3 platform using mssql 2008.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Without understanding the whole problem it's hard to give advice, but this sounds like an odd solution.  I assume you've done everything you can to optimize the query/queries that pull the larger data set?  Are you having to pull too many rows into ASP.Net?

Comment: Do you just want to get a comma separated list of values?  Do you just want to do a bulk export of the data?  As Ann asks, you really need to provide more information.

Comment: Actually,There are three or more tables for storing only product information.Means Product's prices are stored in different table,its descriptions stores in different table etc.So what I want to do is DE-normalize these information and convert it into binary and stores into another table so that i can retrieve only binary.But I want do this using sql programming. So how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a blog entry that explains how to write to a text file from SQL Server . . . http://blog.data-miners.com/2012/01/writing-to-text-file-from-sql-server.html.

You can use this to technique to write each row to a file.

Comment: but How to convert into binary?